# Remove loading spinner from splash screen in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello I'm building an app with Ionic, and I want to remove the loading spinner on splash screen when the app starts, any solution for this?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this to your `config.xml`-file:

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

[Here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#preferences) are som more preferences you can make use of.